# Files is deleting before its used in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node js and i'm trying to do the following:

```
function createPasswordfile(content)
{
    fs.writeFile(passwordFileName,content, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Failed on creating the file " + err)
        } 
    });

    fs.chmodSync(passwordFileName, '400');
}

function deletePasswordFile()
{
    fs.chmodSync(passwordFileName, '777');
    fs.unlink(passwordFileName,function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('successfully deleted');
    });
}
```

and there are three statements which call these functions:

```
createPasswordfile(password)
someOtherFunction() //which needs the created password file
deletePasswordFile()
```

The problem I'm facing is when I add the `deletePasswordFile()` method call, I get error like this:

```
Failed on creating the file Error: EACCES, open 'password.txt'
successfully deleted
```

Since its non blocking, I guess the `deletePasswordFile` function deletes the file before other function make use of it.

If `deletePasswordFile` is commented out, things are working fine.

How should I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writeFile` is asynchronous, so it's possible the file is still being written when you try and delete it.

Try changing to `writeFileSync`.

```
fs.writeFileSync(passwordFileName, content);
```

Comment: Now I get error `TypeError: Bad arguments
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:960:11)`

Comment: Thanks it worked. Really hard to debug the async code

Comment: @batman you get used to it... Not that that's necessarily a good thing. :-)